# How to show html page with "embedded" images on Android?

Tags: android, html, url, webview, base64

I use WebView in my own app to show html pages which I download them, through our custom secured connection, as files without using http protocol, so far so good. This is ok when html includes only plain text (with simple tags like ,  etc...). I than use webview.loadData() method to show the page.

The problem I get is when I want to download an html page with embedded images in it (based on Base64 encoding scheme) and than show it in a WebView. I  use the method:
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl);

With that method, I somehow can't manage to show the images in WebView. I hope someone can give a simple example, hints or an example how to do it correctly.

The problem is, I have the html page as a data buffer, with the embedded images in it. We don't use webservers to download an html page, we download it as a file from a fileserver.
Thank you.